# NoClassDefFoundError with Open API with Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I upgraded to Spring boot 3.0.7 and am trying to get my Open API (swagger) working again, with these dependencies (per [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/v2/)):

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

...but when I build my app, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiWebMvcResource] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1de0aca6]
```

...with a "Caused By" of:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
```

When I look in the `OpenApiWebMvcResource` that's in the `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core:1.7.0` jar, it indeed imports from `javax` instead of `jakarta`:

```
package org.springdoc.webmvc.api;
    
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
...
```

So is this an issue with `openapi-webmvc-core`, or am I wiring something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

had same issue after upgrade.

you need to add only one dependency which is springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api and No additional configuration is needed. Remove the dependency
springdoc-openapi-ui

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

you don't need to specify packagesToscan[] or no need to use withClassAnnotation(RestController.class)), it'll take care by itself as it look for @RestController Annotation and generate the doc.

https://springdoc.org/v2/#spring-webmvc-support

Comment: This helped. But additionally I removed jackson-databind dependency to avoid some compilation errors "
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
        </dependency>"

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Spring Boot 3.0.5 and Java 17) apart from adding the following

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also had to add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Spring Doc /v2 guide](https://springdoc.org/v2/), I only needed to bring in the `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` dependency, but NOT the `springdoc-openapi-ui`.  So when my pom.xml looked like:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

...that error went away, and it worked.

Note that for whatever reason, I also needed to pull in these dependencies as well, otherwise I got a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jakarta.xml.bind.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>${org.glassfish.jaxb.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered similar issue when migrating to springboot 3 from springboot2, I added `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` as recommended then I have got the above issue, upon investigating the dependency tree I see that `springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0` is in the path through the maven transitive dependency feature.
So just had to exclude the following dependency and then everything worked like a charm.