# Unable to setup swagger with spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I created a spring boot application along with gradle.
I added following gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
    
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Then i added a controller:

```
package com.google.demoapp.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Tag(name = "Message API")
public class MessageController {

    @GetMapping("/message")
    @Operation(summary = "Get a message")
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello, this is a GET request!";
    }

    @PostMapping("/message")
    @Operation(summary = "Post a message")
    public String postMessage(@RequestBody String message) {
        return "You posted: " + message;
    }
}
```

Then i added swaggerConfig class

```
package com.google.demoapp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
//@EnableSwagger2 // You can remove this annotation for Swagger 3
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30) // Use OAS_30 for Swagger 3
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.test.demoapp")) // Replace with your package name
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("My RESTful Service")
                .description("A simple RESTful service with Swagger documentation")
                .version("1.0")
                .contact(new Contact("Your Name", "", "your.email@example.com"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

I am building code using : gradelw clean build -x test

I am running code using: gradlew bootRun

After this when i try to access swagger using http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

I am get following error:

[image]

please help me fix this error.

Comment: which spring-boot vesion do you use? if your using spring-boot 3.x.x then please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76325399/noclassdeffounderror-with-open-api-with-spring-boot-3/76325476#76325476

Answer (score 0):

You use Swagger ui 3. you dont create config file. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation. you must be follow step by step. İf create config file you should swagger 2

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot 3.0, don't support Spring Fox, you can use Spring Doc. Guide to migrate spring fox to spring docs [here](https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html)

Add dependency maven:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

After that, you can access these end-points below.

api-docs url: `http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs`

swagger-ui: `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned here, [NoClassDefFoundError with Open API with Spring Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76325399/noclassdeffounderror-with-open-api-with-spring-boot-3/76325476#76325476)

you need to add only one dependency which is springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api and No additional configuration is needed. Remove the dependency springdoc-openapi-ui

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

you don't need to specify packagesToscan[] or no need to use withClassAnnotation(RestController.class)), it'll take care by itself as it look for @RestController Annotation and generate the doc.

https://springdoc.org/v2/#spring-webmvc-support