Which version of Springdoc is compatible with Spring boot 3.2.8?
Which version of Springdoc (springdoc-openapi) is compatible with Spring Boot 3.2.8?
I'm unable to open Swagger UI via localhost.
I have a project that runs on Spring Boot 3.2.8 and cannot downgrade to the version below that.
The dependency which I'm using in pom.xml is springdoc-openapi-ui version 1.7.0.

While it may be legitimate question, it's OT here. Particullary How to run swagger? part is clearly OT.

springdoc-openapi version 2.3.0 works fine for me

Thanks for the replies. May be the way of asking question is not right. But my intent was to run the code only and I tried everything possible at my end. Please don't judge people on the basis of asking the question. And secondly I know how to run swagger

Simple answer: springdoc-openapi version 2.x will be only supported for Spring Boot 3.x.
Just add these dependencies given below if it's a Maven project:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

Add this line in application.properties:
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html

It will work.
Output:

Read the V1 docs & V2 docs. It's mentioned properly.

Thanks for answering this works for me too.

It hasn't worked for me. I have added both dependencies. My spring boot version is 3.0.0


@NelsonEkpenyong Remove springdoc-openapi-ui dependency from your pom.xml. It will work.

@NelsonEkpenyong See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76325399/noclassdeffounderror-with-open-api-with-spring-boot-3

I have removed it, but I get the same error.
        <dependency>             <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>             <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>             <version>2.6.0</version>         </dependency>         <dependency>             <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>             <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>             <version>2.6.0</version>         </dependency>

springdoc-openapi : 2.3.x - 2.5.x is compatible with spring boot 3.2.x
You can find the compatibility matrix of springdoc-openapi with spring-boot from link below :
compatibility matrix of springdoc-openapi with spring-boot
